# PDF, PPT, DOC, etc to TEXT

Tags: pdf, docx, doc, plaintext, odt

Maybe these should be separate questions, one for each format, but...

What are the most RELIABLE **libraries** (in any language), **binaries** (for any platform), or **webservices** (free or not free) for **converting** diverse "text-containing" formats into **plain text**?

By reliable, I mean near 100% ability to extract ALL of the **human-readable text** while NOT EXTRACTING "code" or "markup".

By **text-containing formats**, I mean: all the most common things like PDF, PPT, DOC, DOCX, RTF, HTML, ".PAGES", ".KEYNOTE", ODT, etc etc

Please suggest both packages/services that **support many** of these formats as well as those that only **support one**.  In addition, are there software **"stacks" that "tie together"** many packages/services for the purpose of converting to text?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.filebuzz.com/files/Ascii_Convert/1.html <--This link will take you to a list of converters that can convert a PDF and other types of files to an ASCII format (plain text).
For Word documents, you can do this with out a software.  For example, for Word documents, when you click 'Save As', it will open up a dialog box that will have a 'Save as Type' drop down list.  Select 'Plain Text *.txt' and it will save your file in plain text.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the [Apache Tika toolkit](http://tika.apache.org/) detects and extracts metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby, take a look at [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu). It's a wrapper for [Apache TIKA](http://tika.apache.org/) and supports a variety of document formats which includes the following:

- Microsoft Office OLE 2 and Office Open XML Formats (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx)
- OpenOffice.org OpenDocument Formats (.odt, .ods, .odp)
- Apple iWorks Formats
- Rich Text Format (.rtf)
- Portable Document Format (.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Extract Text](http://www.bullzip.com/products/ext/info.php).

From the description: "Extract text from documents such as PDF and Microsoft Word files. It will save the extracted text in a file. Works with .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, and many more." Requires Microsoft.NET Framework 4.0.